# Three table in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
=================
Table : tb_kategori
- id_kategori (primary key)
- name_kategori
=================
=================
Table : tb_product
- id_product (primary key)
- id_kategori (foreign key)
- name_product
=================
=================
Table : tb_images
- id_images (primary key)
- id_product (foreign key)
- file_images
=================
```

i want to display in html :

and i get id_kategori from URL : **product.php?id_kategori=1**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="[file_images]">
    <div>
      <h1>[name_product]</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

how call SQL in one query ???

Comment: Not to be rude; but you should try to do a little more research online. There are millions of articles that handle these SQL-basics.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: if the value of the category is not shown on the html two tables in one query will suffice.

Comment: ok thankz all .. i must be change this table

Comment: your html doesn't even have a query running yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * 
FROM
     tb_kategori k,tb_product p,tb_images i
WHERE k.id_kategori = p.id_kategori
  AND p.id_product = i.id_product
```